# Why is onKeyPress on TextInput not working in React Native (Android)?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native and testing on android.  I have added a onKeyPress to my TextInput but it is not being triggered by me clicking on the keyboard in the emulator (and yes I use the mouse to click the keys).  Does anyknow know how to get onKeyPress to work or know of another way to detect a key press on the enter (done) key on the Android keyboard?

It never even gets into the function it should be calling (searchProducts).

```
searchProducts = () => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        this.props.searchFunc(this.state.term);
    }
}

searchSuggestions = searchTerm => {
    if (this.timeoutId)
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.props.autofillFunc(searchTerm), 500);

    this.setState({
        term: searchTerm
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.autoFocus) {
        this.refs.searchBar.focus();
    }
}

render() {
    const {placeholder} = this.props;
    const autoFocus = this.props.autoFocus;
    return (
        <View style={styles.searchBar}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={{width: '100%'}}>
                <View style={styles.searchBar}>
                    <MBIcon name='ico-24-search' style={styles.searchIcon} />
                        <TextInput 
                            ref='searchBar'
                            style={styles.searchInput} 
                            placeholder={placeholder}

                            onChangeText={this.searchSuggestions}
                            onKeyPress={this.searchProducts.bind(this)}
                            underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
                        />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: `searchProducts = () => { ... }` should be `searchProducts = (e) => { .. }`