# Why does the "Enter" key not trigger onKeyPress in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, onkeypress

I have added an onKeyPress event listener to my text input so that when a user clicks done or go or "enter" on the phone keyboard it will call my searchProducts function.  I was hoping for an onSubmit type of event listener option but was not able to find anything like that so now I have resorted to simply examining each key that was pressed.  When a character key is pressed such as 'j' or 'x' it triggers the onKeyPress event and calls my searchProducts function.  However, when I click done with the mouse OR hit the enter key on the keyboard nothing happens.  How do I get this to trigger the onKeyPress event listener??

```
searchProducts = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        this.props.searchFunc(this.state.term);
    }
}

<TextInput 
    ref='searchBar'
    style={styles.searchInput} 
    placeholder={placeholder}

    onChangeText={this.searchSuggestions}
    onKeyPress={this.searchProducts.bind(this)}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
/>
```

Comment: Just a hint: when you define `searchProducts` method as arrow function `searchProducts = (e) => `, you can use it as `onKeyPress={this.searchProducts)`, without binding

Comment: Rather than asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536369/why-is-onkeypress-on-textinput-not-working-in-react-native-android) twice please consider adding a bounty to the first question to attract more answers.

Comment: Active reading [`TextInput` documentation for `onEndEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onendediting) and [`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [onSubmitEditing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting) which is:

> Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is
> pressed. Invalid if multiline={true} is specified.

It will be called after pressing 'done' button on keyboard.

Comment: It worked, but only when I wrote `onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}` (Keyboard is imported from react-native.

Answer (score -1):

onKeyPress should be triggered when you hit return key, check if you have another event in this page that cancel this one from being triggered
if yes use

event.stopPropagation()