# How do I trigger a function on TextInput when users presses enter?

Tags: react-native

I am working on an app for a company. I want the `TextInput` to trigger a function after the user adds their text and presses enter on `TextInput`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Something for us to reproduce? I can understand if you can't because this is for a business.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle [`onKeyPress`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onkeypress) to do that.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function UselessTextInput() {
  const handleOnKeyPress = event =>{
    const key = event.nativeEvent.key
    // As I remember key for enter button is "Enter", but if not you can console.log(key) and hit enter to check the value
    if(key ==="Enter"){
      //do you stuff here
    }
  }
  return (
    <TextInput
      onKeyPress={handleOnKeyPress}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this. I had no idea how to go about it.

Comment: I am glad it helped. If it really help you, please considering about accept my answer.

Comment: Actually, that did not work. Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584382/why-does-the-enter-key-not-trigger-onkeypress-in-react-native/50584524

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSubmitEditing` for executing your function on enter or submit a button from the keyboard.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function UselessTextInput() {
  const executeOnEnter=()=>{ 
    alert('hi i am pressed')
   }
  return (
    <TextInput
      onSubmitEditing={executeOnEnter}
    />
  );
}
```